# Writing bytes to file

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I'm currently working on a DBF file manager and I'm having some problems...

One of the elements that compose the header is the last date that the file was updated.
The problem is: the field format is YYMMDD and it MUST have 3 bytes.

**How is it possible to write a date using that format using only 3 bytes?** Also, another field represents the type of the file (if it have a memo or not).

The file type in my case is 03h and this field MUST use only 1 byte. I'm pretty confused.

Comment: Well, think about how many different numbers can be represented with a single byte: 256. So, you can store any 2 (decimal) digit number (0-99) inside a single byte, with plenty of room to spare. Does this help?

Comment: I think i got the idea but how do I do it? I was using putc without sucess

Comment: What went wrong with putc?

Comment: I was not sure how to do it so I used putc to write the date, char by char. Is that wrong?

Comment: Chars take one byte each. So if you need to write 3 bytes exactly, you need to write a number which has the composition that you want. See my answer below. I hope I'm not misunderstanding your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would hold your data in 3 bytes as

- first byte = year
- second byte = month
- third byte = day

There's plenty of room in each byte for the domain of each field (year, month, day). You could write them in an integer with bit-shifting operations, like this:

```
int year = 13;
int month = 7;
int day = 26;
int my_date = (year << 16) | (month << 8) | day;
```

Edit:

What I did in my_date: I basically concatenated the information you need (year, month, day) into a series of bits (8 bits per information field), *as an integer*. You know an `int` is 4 bytes. Consider for starters that `my_date` is 0, that is, all 32 bits are 0. The 4 bytes of it are as follows ("|" denotes concatenation; that's for ease of reading):

```
my_date = 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

When I write `year << 16` I have

```
year << 16 = 0 | year | 0 | 0
```

In a similar fashion,

```
month << 8 = 0 | 0 | month | 0
day = 0 | 0 | 0 | day
```

When I apply the OR operator on all of them, my_date looks like this:

```
my_date = 0 | year | month | day
```

Accessing them:

```
year = (my_date & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
month = (my_date & 0xFF00) >> 8;
day = my_date & 0xFF;
```

Edit: how accessing works. We previously had

```
my_date = 0 | year | month | day
```

If you do, for example, an AND with 0xFF00, which is `0 | 0 | FF | 0`, you get

```
my_date & 0xFF00 = 0 | 0 | month | 0
```

Now all you need to do is shift your data back, so

```
(my_date & 0xFF00) >> 8 = 0 | 0 | 0 | month = month
```

Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Can you explain what did you do in my_date? I'm still learning the language

Answer (score 0):

First byte for year: 2000 + YY. Can count from 2000 till 2255

Second byte for month: 1-12

Third byte for day: 1-31